# Build Android Native Extension without Flash Builder

Tags: android, flash, native

Ok, quick question . . .

Is it possible to build (compile) an Android Native Extension (ANE) without using Flash Builder.

Im trying to build an extension within eclipse but anywhere i look it says to use Flash builder somewhere throughout the process. I dont have flash builder, only Flash CS6 and Eclipse. Is there a way to package and get a ANE file using only flash and eclipse?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's some documentation on how to package .SWFs into an ANE: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/WSf268776665d7970d-2482335412ffea65006-8000.html

as far as getting your .AS code to .SWFs and .SWCs, the mxlmc (for the .AS->.SWF) and compc (makes .SWCs) will both run outside of flash builder (and are found along with adt in the free to download flex sdk: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html )

(.as, .jpg, .swc, etc) ==mxmlc==> (.swf)

(.as, .jpg, etc) ==compc==> (.swc)

(.swc, .swf) ==adt==> (ANE)

Comment: thank you I will have a play today and let you know how I get on :)

Answer (score 0):

its not an answer but what I have to say will not fit into the comments box . . .

ok now im really lost and confused.

heres what iv done, I have created an android project within eclipse. within this project I have included the flashruntimeextensions.jar file and created all necessary files within the eclipse project(that im aware of)(a TorchExtension.java file which returns a new Context.java file, in which i use map.put("torchy", new TorchFunction()); and then obviously a torchFunction.java file which contains code to "turn torch on".

am I correct in thinking I need to export this as a SWC or ANE file, which I can then import to flash through the java build path?

or do I have to create some form of action-script library to talk between flash and native code? i have gone through countless pre existing ANEs but I have failed to get any working, I feel like im missing something important.

Comment: I think people usually edit in updates to their original post (but I'm new here too)... you shouldn't think of mxmlc, compc, and adt as having anything to do with java (even though they're probably written in java and have lovely ant-task wrappers if you so desire).  there's analogs to including jars, etc, but it's a totally different thing